# Run Emacs on Windows host, docker container on Linux server

Tags: tramp, docker

I have a Windows 10 machine at work, on which our IT refuses to install Docker. Instead, they want me to run Docker on a remote Linux server that I access through PuTTY. I have a PuTTY session called "ringer" that I use to reach the server, and I've set up PuTTY with keys so that I don't need to type in a password. I can open a file in my Windows Emacs (actually MSYS2) with address

```
/plinkx:ringer:~/
```

I would like to use my local Emacs (29.2) to access the remote Docker container. I've looked at `tramp-container.el`, but I remain confused. On the one hand, I should start the address with `/docker:`, but then on the other hand, how can I access the PuTTY `ringer` session?

Some guidance on where to start would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

tramp-container.el from ELPA is outdated. Tramp comes with builtin docker support.

In order to access a docker container on the remote host, you might use a multi-hop access. Try something like `/plinkx:ringer|docker:container_name:`